# How do I share common code between 2 react native applications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two sister applications, lets say A and B providing similar solutions to 2 distinct user bases. Both applications are in development. There is to be a whole lot of common code shared like utils, UI components, Networking components etc.
I come from an android background. How do I create module common ?

```
-> common /
   -- C.js

-> app A /
   -- android/
   -- ios/
   -- index.js
   -- src
       | - A.js - references C

-> app B / 
   -- android/
   -- ios/
   -- index.js
   -- src
       | - B.js - references C
```

Comment: or just make a shared github repository and `yarn` or `npm install` from that repository for both of the applications when you compile an apk

Comment: I thought of doing this way, but since the apps has just begun development, and multiple developers will be constantly changing adding to apps and the module, could there be a better way ?

Comment: Isn't that what github is for? for multiple developers to work on the same project and merge code... etc.

Comment: I use git submodule for this situation. I made a repository for `/common` then make it the submodule of app A and app B.

Comment: Let me rephrase, I'm a beginner here, I though of doing it via github submodule, but how do i create the common module in the first place? is there something like create-react module?

Comment: just create a github repository, and then put the url to your repository in your package.json.